# How can I tell what events are bound to an object?

Tags: jquery

I am using jqGrid (http://www.trirand.com/blog/) to display some read-only data.  The resizeable columns are interfering with other draggable elements on the page (they get stuck when dragged over the region where the columns can be resized).

I want to unbind() whatever is allowing the columns to be resized, presumably on mouseover, but I can't figure out how to determine what callbacks the objects currently have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('body').click(function(){ alert('test' )})

var foo = $.data( $('body').get(0), 'events' ).click
// you can query $.data( object, 'events' ) and get an object back, then see what events are attached to it.

$.each( foo, function(i,o) {
    alert(i) // guid of the event
    alert(o) // the function definition of the event handler
});
```

Copied from my previous answer @ [jQuery check if event exists on element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515069/jquery-check-if-event-exists-on-element)

Just adopt it to fit your selector