# jQuery check if onClick exists on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I found the way to [check if event exists on element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515069/jquery-check-if-event-exists-on-element). But it's not work on the events which is not delegated by jQuery:

When I try,

```
$("a").data("events");
```

for this.

```
<a href="#" onClick="alert('Hello, World!')" />
```

It returned undefined.

Is there any way to check if `onClick` exists on elements with jQuery?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do:

```
if ($('a').attr("onClick") != undefined) {}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just do:

```
if( myelement.onclick != null )
{
   //onclick exists
}
else
{
   //onclick doesn't exist
}
```

No need for jQuery.

Comment: I'm trying to test if an event listener has been setup as part of a JS Unit test... how how can i test if it has been setup or not??

This isn't working, always returns true... 
console.log(document.body.click.length);
    document.body.addEventListener('click', function () { alert('hi')},false)
    console.log(document.body.click.length);

Answer (score 3):

```
if( $('#elementName').click == undefined)  
   { //event handler doesn't exist }
else 
   { //handler exists }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following things should also work

```
if ($(yourElement).attr("onClick").length != 0) {}

if ($(yourElement).attr("onClick").size() != 0) {}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For sure there are some valid answers here, this was a good one that got me going.

```
if ($('a').attr("onClick") != undefined) {}
```

But I found the best answer for you, as it was for since we are both dealing with hyperlinks, would looking for the href attribute.

```
if ($('a').attr("href") != undefined) {}
```

I particularly liked this approach.