# Using JavaScript or jQuery how to check if event exists on the window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

#### Setup

I've attached an event to the 'window' object, and I would like to check that it's there via code.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e){ /*...*/ }, false)
```

#### Attempts

I've tried the simple, and jQuery, without luck. I have **more attempts up on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NickJosevski/A8Fy9/1/)**.

```
window.beforeunload //is undefined as is window.onbeforeunload

$(window).data('events') //not working either
```

**Is this possible?**

There are similar questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515069/jquery-check-if-event-exists-on-element) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859171/jquery-check-if-onclick-exists-on-element)) about the DOM, and other elements, but none of the approaches in those that I have tried have worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `in` operator...

```
'onbeforeunload' in window;  // true (if supported)
```

---

If supported, the property will exist, though the value will be `null`.

Comment: Thanks. Works in IE, Chrome, but not FF.

Comment: @NickJosevski: Works for me in FF 10. When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean? What result are you getting?

Comment: Oh that's right, tested in FF 3.6... Works in 10. Thanks :) Problem still in Opera 11.61 but I can live with that.