# How check if an event listener exists in javascript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I try to find a way to check if an `eventListener` already exists in a window, I've tried the solution in this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270562/using-javascript-or-jquery-how-to-check-if-event-exists-on-the-window) and more other solutions, but nothing works for me.

Here is the code:

```
   checkEvent=function()
   {
    if('keydown' in window)
        console.log('exist');
    else
        console.log('not_exist');
   }
```

And here is my eventListener that I add on my page Load

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", PayKeydownHandler);
```

But the first code, returns `'not_exist'` as a result

PS: The function `checkEvent()`, i call it in onclick of ENTER keydown.

Any help please? Thank's in advance.

Comment: First of all, note that your function looks at `window`, but you add the event listener to `document`. Second, if you're only going to add one listener, you could probably just directly set the `onkeydown` property and then have `checkEvent` check if that property is set to a function. Otherwise, I don't believe there's a built in way to do this.

Comment: See the answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430672/javascript-how-to-check-if-event-already-added

Comment: @pushkin you're right, I didn't even pay attention that I'm working with document while, I'm testing on window. But even with that I have the same result. Thank's for your reply

Comment: @CoursesWeb I have tried this solution too, but the console showed me an error in the syntax. Thank's for your reply

Answer (score -3):

try this

```
jQuery._data( window, "events" );
```

it work in jquery 1.8 . Read [this jQuery blog post](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/08/building-a-slimmer-jquery/).

Comment: Thank's for your reply, but this is not useful in my case.

Comment: He never told he was using jQuery...