# Capture all events (click, change, onmouseover, e.t.c) for a given element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anyway that I can check if an existing element has event handlers attached to it?  Suppose a simple javascript method adds a click event to some div.example (sans jquery), so there are not attribute tags, is it possible to then, using jquery, to capture the event that was attached?  I tried to accomplish this using the code below to no avail:

```
$( '.example' ).each( function() {
var newObj = $(this);
$.each($(newObj).data("events"), function(i, event) {
    alert(i);
        $.each(event, function(j, h) {
            alert(h.handler);
        });
});
```

});

Comment: There is no need to do `$($(this))`.

Comment: You can get all events (and the associated handlers) using the method described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515069/jquery-check-if-event-exists-on-element).

Comment: Also, what's `$('#...').each` supposed to do? There is hopefully only one ID per document.

Comment: And, it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/qQL38/. You just missed the last `});` of the first `.each`.

Comment: $(this).data('events') only holds events that were bound using jQuery.

Comment: I thought jQuery's .data() implementation is specific to jQuery.  if another batch of javascript attaches a function to an element without using an attribute or jQuery, you'll have to find it using plain javascript I think.

Comment: "Also, what's $('#...').each supposed to do? There is hopefully only one ID per document." 

Pasting error, this is supposed to be a class, not id :-)  I will change it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$( '#elm1' ).each( function() {

 $.each($(this).data("events"), function(i, event) {
        alert(i);
        $.each(event, function(j, h) {
            alert(h.handler);
        });
 });
});
```

Comment: jQuery's .data() is specific to jQuery.  It will not always work for not "bound using jQuery" events.

Comment: Yes, you should use it only if you are using jQuery library.

Comment: I was not aware that .data() was specific to events created/attached via the jQuery object.  Thanks for the quick response.  I will use regular javascript to fish this out instead.

Comment: You question it self shows you are using jQuery then why do you want to use plain javascript and worry about cross browser issues?

Comment: .data is not event specific, it stores arbitrary data associated with the specified element. [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/]

Comment: The events are attached by method(s) in javascript files that I can not edit - more specifically, the files are controlled by an existing framework.  I want(ed) to utilize jQuery to augment existing functionality.

Comment: This solution only works for "jQuery events", not javascript events in general.

Comment: It's not clear; even developers which are "using the jQuery library" will not see all events using this code. Any native events will not be seen.