# jQuery selector for ANY element -- does this exist?

Tags: jquery

How do I capture an event for ANY element in jQuery? Obviously `$("*").click()` doesn't work. Is there some sort of selector for any element that is clicked, etc.?

Comment: of course it works, did you try it?

Comment: `$(document).on('click', function(e) { //do stuff });`

Comment: "Obviously it doesn't work" -- please support this claim with a fiddle.

Comment: Maybe this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710939/capture-all-events-click-change-onmouseover-e-t-c-for-a-given-element-using

Comment: Sorry, I meant doesn't work for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
$(document).on('click', function(){})

$("body").on('click', function(){})
```