# jQuery Selector for all Click-Handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery

**What i have:**

```
$('#main').find('*').on('click.stop', function() {return false;});
```

---

**What i want:**
Changing the selector `'*'` to `all classes with a bound click_handler` because of performance issues.

---

**My idea:** Assigning additional classes when binding a handler to a class.

---

**Problem with idea:** The amount of code i would have to change is too damn high! and i am very lazy...

Comment: +1 for truth, -1 for laziness.

Comment: Have a look at this plugin, jQuery Event Filter http://www.codenothing.com/archives/jquery/event-filter/

Comment: Sorry if a fact about me makes my question bad. And sorry that i want to save time and keep my code at a minimum. :'(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your expression to do this. jQuery does not support this selector natively.

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {     
  click: function(elem) { 
       return $(elem).hasEvent('click');    
  } 
});
```

Then, you can use:
`$("*:click").on('click.stop',...`

hasEvent:

```
$.fn.hasEvent = function(event, fn) {
if (!event) { return this; }
var has = {
      event: false,
      namespace: false,
      handler: false
    },
    events = this.data("events"),
    namespace = event.split(".");
event = namespace.shift();
namespace = namespace.join(".");
if (events) {
  if (!namespace) { has.namespace = true; }
  if (!fn) { has.handler = true; }
  if (event in events) {
    $.each(events[event], function(i, v) {
      if (namespace) {
        if (namespace === v.namespace && event === v.type) {
          has.namespace = true;
          has.event = true;
          if (fn && fn === v.handler) { has.handler = true; }
        }
      }
      else {
        if (event === v.type) {
          has.event = true;
          if (fn && fn === v.handler) { has.handler = true; }
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
return has.event && has.namespace && has.handler;
};
```

Comment: You are welcome!
And the simplest way is missing from my answer

`jQuery.expr[":"].click = "jQuery(a).hasEvent('click');";`

Comment: Then i have to define .hasEvent() first since it results in a no method error

Comment: Sorry, I am very tired!
I forgot the $() `return $(elem).hasEvent('click');`
http://jsfiddle.net/UgnwN/

Comment: Oh should have seen that myself :P
Thanks alot master!

Answer (score 3):

You can select all elements with a clickhandler like that:

```
var e = $.data($(body).get(0), 'events').click;
```

If you have done that, you can loop through these elements with the $.each loop and apply your function/ event to them :)

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery check if event exists on element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515069/jquery-check-if-event-exists-on-element)

the answers to this may help you. this question was to check if an event exists on an element.