# Ask if event has listener in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

A function triggers an event and passes on some data which then will possibly be processed by a listener. If not, the function wants to process the data by herself. Well, as I don't know if the package was handled or not, my idea was to find out if there is a listener at all. Is there a way to do this or does anyone have better ideas to my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tried `$(element).hasEventListener(type)` ?

Comment: Looks like that's a plugin: https://github.com/sebastien-p/jquery.hasEventListener

Comment: All events are binded to some elements. So in Chrome you have developer tools -> elements tab -> event listeners tab (in right side). Guess there is something similar in other browsers' devtools.

Comment: What kind of listener are you talking about?

Comment: This answere seems to show do what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1515073/355499

Comment: Thanks all for you help. I then solved the problem by checking the lenght of the `$.data('events')` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can to this with jQuery prior to 1.8 like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#click_here").click(function() {
  alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});

 console.log( $('#click_here').data('events') );

});

</script>

<div id="click_here">Click here</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a plugin mainly to be used in your tests.

```
// Example usage
$('.foo').hasEvent('click', someHandler) 
// returns true if someHandler is bound via jQuery on '.foo' 
// for the click event
```

The plugin is tested to work with jQuery 1.7 and up

[The plugin is hosted on github](https://github.com/Zorbash/hasEvent)

Answer (score 1):

I had a VERY similar problem. It's never been something that's been properly supported in jquery and instead was kind of a hack. So you could do it prior to version 1.8 in jquery by using

`data('events')`

After 1.8, you can use:

`$._data( $('.element')[0], 'events' );`

BUT if you're trying to do what I was doing... make sure an event handler is only assigned once on a control (i.e. a save button after some form validation), then you can either:

1. Add a class and remove it to indicate whether an element has an event (ugly).
2. Remove any handers before assigning it i.e.

`$('element').unbind('event');
$('element').on('click', save);`