# How to check whether jQuery handle is on or off?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handle

I have something like the following in my js code...

```
    a.off('mouseover').on('mouseover', function() {
        overlayTrigger(this);
    });
    a.off('click').on('click', function() {
        overlayTrigger(this, true);
    });
```

And then later on during the mouse click, i remove them:

```
    $(obj).off('mouseover');
    $(obj).off('mouseout');
```

But I want the next mouse click, if those handles are off, I want to re-enable them... However, I don't know how to check whether 'mouseover' is off or not...

Digging through google is a little bit difficule, because the keywords "on" and "off" and "mouseover" aren't the method to find what i want... >.<

Any help/hint would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Well...if the click handler is `off`, then you can't really have any logic on the next click, since the handler is...off? I also don't quite understand why you would do this: `a.off('mouseover').on('mouseover', function() {`

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515069/jquery-check-if-event-exists-on-element

Comment: That is when i try to bind it, is in different part of the code, anyhow, i read it somewhere here that is to prevent binding the event multiple time to the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of events bound to an object using jQuery.data.

**If you are using jQuery 1.8 or above you will need to use the following:**

[jQuery post here.](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/08/building-a-slimmer-jquery/)

```
$._data(elem, 'events');
```

`elem` should be an HTMLElement, *NOT* a jQuery object or selector. If you have a jQuery object already you can use replace `elem` with `elem.get(0)`.

**jQuery version below 1.8:**

```
$(elem).data('events');
```

This will return an object with the events. You can then check to see if they are undefined or not.

NOTE: Keep in mind that if there are no event handlers on the element, the data will return as *undefined*.

Comment: Wow, thank you, how did one even find this to begin with!!! This is perfect. I was monitoring `$._data(obj, 'events');` and could clearly see the event being remove one by one as it go. Much appreciated. :)

Comment: Haha you are welcome. Sometimes when there isn't clear documentation, digging in and looking at the code helps. :) Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

while re-enabling them , you could do this

```
$(obj).off('mouseover').on('mouseover',function(){...});
```