# Is there a way to figure out this from a jQuery click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there some equivalent of `this` that can be derived from `e.target`

`e.target` can be a child of `this`.

you could do `$(e.target).closest("a")` if you know what the selector is for the element that the click function is bound to.

But, what if you don't know the selector?

---

**EDIT**:
for clarification:

I'm experiencing a
`TypeError: Cannot call method 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined` error when I try to test a click function.

I have bound a click function to an element like so:
`$(".original_list_trigger").click(Helpers.originalTextButtonClick);`

and that is defined like this:

```
Helpers: {
        originalTextButtonClick: function(e) {
            var self = $(this);
            console.log(self);
...
}...}
```

console.log(self) doesn't give an element, but the function itself, which isn't what I want. $(this) should be the element that has the function bound to the click event, right?

This is $(this): [image]
so, it looks like $(this), is the object `Helpers`... :-\

---

UPDATE:

Basically, I'm dumb.
the problem was being caused by this being invoked:

`Helpers.originalTextButtonClick();` <- I wasn't passing anything as e, so.. of course e.anything wouldn't be defined.

Since I'm running tests through Jasmine, http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/, I need to find a way to mock the event object, and `this`. Or I could just trigger a click on the element (which I'll probably do, since that's easier)

Comment: Your goal might be unclear. Why not use `this` ?

Comment: Have you logged out the **event** object? I'm sure you can find what you're looking for :)

Comment: Put `console.log(e);` in your code and then have a look for what you need in the console.  Alternatively, show us the code you have and tell us what you want to get from it.

Comment: may be this what you looking for,  how to detect if elem has onclick event? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515069/jquery-check-if-event-exists-on-element

Comment: Added some clarification

Comment: Are you saying you're now doing something like this : $(".original_list_trigger").click(Helpers.originalTextButtonClick(someObject)) ? If so, that's not what you want to do. That is actually passing the return value of the function as the callback, not the reference to the function you want to call.  $().click() accepts a callback function that will execute when the event is triggered. jQuery normalizes and enhances the event object across browsers and then passes it as the first argument to the callback function. You don't/can't manually pass anything into the callback.

Comment: well, I wouldn't be passing just any object, I'd need to pass an event object, right?

Also, I ended up just calling .click(), and then testing the results of the bound function. Not as separate as I want, but it'll have to work, since my function uses `this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the currentTarget prop

```
  $("p").click(function(event) {
      alert( event.currentTarget === this ); // true
    });
```

[JQuery event.currentTarget](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/)

after edits:

originalTextButtonClick: function(e) {
            var self = $(e.currentTarget);
            console.log(self);
...
}

Comment: I added some clarification

Comment: I see. What if you log the e.currentTarget ? Is that what you expect ?

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentTarget' of undefined` nope. lol

Comment: does `e` not get passed along when you bind functions to a click? I thought that was supposed to work like that o.o

Comment: aren't you receiving a totally empty e parameter ?

Comment: I found the problem... I feel really dumb now >_<
     Helpers.originalTextButtonClick(); <- causing the error.

Comment: what do you mean? clarify! I'm curious now :P

Comment: Oh I see now. You were calling the function manually, not by attaching it to a event, right?

Comment: yup. silly me. sometimes I wish javascript had stricter exceptions on how many parameters are required for functions. :-\

Comment: yep, that's the core of javascript programming anyway! glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Helpers: {
        originalTextButtonClick: function(e) {
            var closestAnchorElement = $(e.currentTarget).closest("a");
...
}...}
```

Comment: I added some clarification

Comment: Please check if this suits your requirements.

Comment: this will come in handy for when I actually need to do this. Turns out the problem was because I had something manually calling the click event, so e isn't going to be defined.
     `Helpers.originalTextButtonClick();` <- I wasn't passing anything as e

Answer (score 0):

We can use -

```
$("p").click(function(event) {
    alert(event.toElement); 
});
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/vA693/)

Comment: a little modification: http://jsfiddle.net/vA693/1/
if you click the text, it doesn't return the id. which, is what my original question would want it to do.