# Check if on event is handled

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check, if a event is handled with .on in jquery?
For example I have added an event handler to the button click event:

```
$(document).on("click", "#button", function(event)  {
    alert("Handled buttonclick event!");
});
```

Now I want to check if the event is handled to prevent assigning the same event handler a second time.

Comment: if you see 2 alerts, it is handled 2 times

Comment: Not very clear what you mean, can you explain more?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515069/jquery-check-if-event-exists-on-element

Comment: This is a delegated event handler. It doesn't make sense to add it a second time. In any case, you can `$(document).data('handler-added', true)` to "remember" that you did.

Comment: @Sumurai8 I don't think the method in that answer will work for delegated handlers.

Comment: That's actually my problem!

Comment: @Barmar it should work just fine - it's because the event handler is bound to the document so you need to check the document object - http://jsfiddle.net/B7zS6/

Comment: @user2727037 Maybe I'm misunderstanding but all you want to do is check if the element is bound to an event right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are delegating to the document - you need to check the document's event handlers

```
$._data(document,'events') // will return all event handlers bound to the document
```

Then you can do check the events you want.. for example click

```
var events = $._data(document,'events').click; // all click events

$.each(events,function(i,v){ // loop through
    v.selector; // will give you all the selectors used in each delegated event
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B7zS6/

each object will contain the following

```
Object {type: "click", origType: "click", data: undefined, handler: function, guid: 2…}
data: undefined
guid: 2
handler: function (event) {
namespace: ""
needsContext: false
origType: "click"
selector: "#button"
type: "click"
__proto__: Object
```

This is assuming your delegated events are bound to the document object though.  So in this case you "MUST" know which element the event handler is actually bound to.  The other answers will probably work a lot better

so this method would not know about

```
$('body').on("click", "#button", function(event)  {
    alert("Handled buttonclick event!");
});
```

or

```
$('parentelement').on("click", "#button", function(event)  {
    alert("Handled buttonclick event!");
});
```

Comment: And `v.handler` contains the associated handler function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `add a button click once only` the you can use [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one) like,

```
$("#button").one("click",function(event)  {
    alert("Handled buttonclick event!");
});
```

`or manually` you can check by `setting` a `variable` like

```
var countClicked=0;
$(document).on("click", "#button", function(event)  {
    alert("You clicked button "+ (++countClicked) + " times");
});
```

Comment: `.one()` makes the handler only run once, it doesn't mean only one handler.