# Are jQuery events duplicated?

Tags: jquery, events

If I create a div with a button like this:

```
var createDiv = function()
{
    // create div HTML...

    // add event
    $('.btn').on('click',function(e)
    { 
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        // do something
    });
}
```

and then create another div with a different id, does Jquery create a duplicate event in memory or does it reference the original?

Comment: Every time `createDiv` is called, you are calling `.on` passing a new function. So you are binding a new event handler every time. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Don't see from the code how you can make a div of a different id.

Comment: @Felix Kling - yes, that's what i meant. I presumed jQuery would negate any duplication on the same class event. This (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5885197/1837472) suggests an unbind before adding an event; seems overkill.

Comment: @user3558931 - the create function was sparse as my question pertains to the event itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will create and bind a new function each time you call `createDiv`.

Check out the docs for the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method. You want to call `on` only once, passing in a selector that will capture all the buttons you're interested in, and only create the new elements in the `createDiv` function.

Comment: Thanks; looks like I need to refactor my events.