# Find elements with click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can each element with a click event found by jQuery (2.2.1)?

This seems to not work anymore:

```
console.log($._data( $(this)[0], 'events' ))
```

Comment: We do not have jQuery 2.2.1 yet.

Comment: The answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515069/jquery-check-if-event-exists-on-element assumes that what the OP has should, or at least used to work. It has been removed since 1.8 See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1515073/227299 and http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/

Comment: @JuanMendes The blog says that getting it with `$(element).data("events")` has been removed, but `$._data(element, "events")` still works. But I wouldn't be surprised if it has changed incompatibly in 2.x.

Comment: i trying to find all elements with an event like click or mousedown (set via jquery or vanilla javascript)

Comment: @Barmar It says that a private, for debugging version is (was) still available. It seems pretty likely to me that it has by now been removed also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$.each($("*"), function(index, value) {
    if ($._data($(value)[0], "events") != undefined) {
         console.log($._data($(value)[0], "events")
                     , window.jQuery().jquery); 
    };
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/3dhMM/

jQuery:

- version: v2.1.2-pre e5190982c40d7ac8ab9bdb2e7e4334f0e123ef66
- url: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js
- date: 2014-07-14T09:04Z