# Make a selector behave like another in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a selector for the `id="original"` element that triggers on click a function called `on_click_behaviour` and I need another selector `id="other"` to mimic/inherit all of its behaviours or just the click.

How can I make the `other` selector inherit all the functions from the `original` so that when i click the `other` selector it will trigger the `on_click_behaviour` as well?

```js
// can not touch this code as it's core
$( "#original" ).click(function() {
  on_click_behaviour();
});
```

```html
<div id="original">close window</div>

<div id="other">close same window</div>
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
$( "#other" ).inherit_behaviours_from( "#original" );
```

Comment: Functions can't contain the - character in their names.

Comment: What you're describing doesn't really make sense. Selectors can't "trigger" functions and `id="original"` is not a selector, it a attribute. Selectors can't mimic behavior or inherit behavior because selectors are *strings* that don't "do" anything. Please show us some code as a demonstration of what you have, and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Selectors don't trigger click functions

Comment: @meagar OP has described the requirement at text of Question adequately. The requirement is to trigger an event handler for `#original`, or the same event handler attached to `#original` when event is dispatched at `#other`,  either programmatically or by user action. Essentially using the same event handler for both elements. Possibly setting `this` at the handler when the event is dispatched.

Comment: please read my updated question again

Comment: @Mauro Do you only want to call the same event handler for `#original` as `#other`, or also set `this` within the event handler of `#original` when `click` occurs at `#other`? Why cannot you attach the same event handler to `#other`? Or use selector `$("#original, #other").click(function(){behaviour();})` to attach same event to both elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to use the functionality that happens when you click the "original" element and it does not involve any variables that are different between the "original" and the "other", you can use this solution.
It doesn't look very good, but it works.

```js
$( "#other" ).click(function() {
  $("#original").click();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You are badly muddling your terms.

- Selectors are *strings* that match 0 or more elements on the page
- Selectors cannot trigger events
- Inheritance doesn't apply here
- You cannot click on selectors

What you're doing is using a selector to find an element, and then binding a function to some event that will be triggered by an interaction with that element.

What you're *trying* to do is bind the same behavior to a second element.

In order to add the same handler to an additional element, you just need to select the second element in addition to the first. You can do that by adding the two selectors together, delimited by a comma:

```
$('#original, #other').click(function () {
  behavior();
})
```

This will select the element with `id="original"` and the element with `id="other"` and then bind the same `click`-handling function to both of them.

Comment: This is correct, but i can not touch the "original" function. I can only add another piece of code to "inherit" the behaviours of the "original". Thanks

Comment: @Mauro Why can't you touch the original function?

Comment: i can't touch it because it's core

Comment: @Mauro Only you are aware of the meaning and significance of "core". Adding "core" as reason why you cannot change the `javascript` does not elaborate on what "core" is. Take note of the information within this Answer. `id="original"` is not a selector, but an attribute name and value pair at an `html` `document`. See [HTML Standard 3.2.4.1 Attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#attributes), [Selectors Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)

Comment: it's a plugin that i can not touch. id="original" is not a selector it's an identifier of a selector for the sake of understanding. please reword it so that it's more understandable and i will update my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger) to dispatch the `click` event attached to `#original` which calls handler assigned to handler `click` event.

```js
function on_click_behaviour() {
  console.log("clicked")
} 

// can not touch this code
$("#original").click(function() {
  on_click_behaviour();
});

$("#other").click(function() {
  $("#original").trigger("click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="original">close window</div>

<div id="other">close same window</div>
```

You can alternatively get the event handler attached to `#original"` `DOM` element using `$._data()`, then attach the handler assigned to `#original` to `#other`.

```js
function on_click_behaviour() {
  console.log("clicked")
} 

// can not touch this code
$("#original").click(function() {
  on_click_behaviour();
});

var originalHandler = $._data($("#original")[0]).events.click[0].handler;

$("#other").on("click", originalHandler);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="original">close window</div>

<div id="other">close same window</div>
```

Comment: what would happen if i don't know that the function is an event on "click" ?? could i just inherit every attached function ??

Comment: @Mauro _"could i just inherit every attached function ??"_ Yes. You can iterate `$._data($("#original")[0]).events` object [Find elements with click event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744967/find-elements-with-click-event/)