# How to check if an element has an event or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, jquery-data

How can I check if an element has an event or not with jQuery?

I would like to clone or store that event for later use.

html,

```
<div class="item">
    <a href="#" class="edit">edit</a>
    <a href="#" class="delete">delete</a>
    <a href="#" class="view">view</a>
</div>
```

jQuery,

```
$(".edit").click(function(){
    return false;
});

$(".delete").click(function(){
    return false;
});

$("a").each( function(i) { 
    $each = this;
    console.log($(this).data('events').click);
    if($(this).data('events')){
        console.log($each.className);
    }
});
```

error,

> TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

I know this similar [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515069/jquery-check-if-event-exists-on-element), but that is where I get my error message from.

Comment: I tried that. thanks. but i get an error as I stated above.