# Check that click event already exist on JQuery 1.11.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m looking for all internet and I cannot find a situation like mine.

I have a jsp(lets call it A.jsp) with an import javascript, which has a onDocumemntReady. In that documentReady I bound an click event for a class element of my A.jsp.

Now The issue is that I have another page with a loop where I iterate and include n A.jsp.

So now what´s happening is that I add this n pages on the DOM and after finish the onDocumentReady is call it for everyone. So what I want to do is just create the "click" events once. Looking on google I cannot find a way to check if the event already exist for JQuery 1.11.1.
Any idea.

Regards.

Comment: Why not just remove the documentReady from A.jsp and include it outside of the loop?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515069/jquery-check-if-event-exists-on-element

Comment: Yes, that what I had before. But that page has to be independent, since in other part of the application is used out of a loop as unique page.

Comment: @ArunPJohny it´s for JQuery 1.11.1, on that version data function does not exist. I already check all Stackoverflow responses :)

Comment: @paul see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/b5rcLo7n/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny that code works like a charm, thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

why not to simply "Off" and "On" events.

example:

```
$(selector).off('click').on('click',function(){//do something});
```

or If you only want one event per selector, use `one`:

```
$(selector).one('click',function(){//do something});
```

> NOTE: For your curiosity, there are plugins avaiable which are
>   supported across required jQuery version.
>   https://github.com/Inducido/jquery-handler-toolkit.js

Comment: I dont understand, for what for I need the on and off?.

Comment: you need to unbind the event on an element before binding it again on the same element to ensure only one instance of event is bonded.

Comment: You should avoid to used `.off()` with only the event names. `[...]When writing code that will be used as a plugin, or simply when working with a large code base, best practice is to attach and remove events using namespaces so that the code will not inadvertently remove event handlers attached by other code. [...]`

Comment: remove the event and create it again is a not elegant solution, but might works. Thanks

Comment: Yes I read that plugin as well. But I dont want to add more third parties libraries. Thanks anyway