# How to avoid conflict between 2 jQuery "on form submit" scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

What I want to achieve is to track form submits.
But because of the many variations that we use for the submit button I want to change my current code:

```
$(document).on('click','input[type="submit"], button[type="submit"]',function(){
```

to something that is universal. And I believe the best approach is the `$("form")`-annotation.

The problem is that for example if a `form` has an ajax script on it, it gets blocked by my `additional` script code.
Basically what I want to achieve is to have both worlds.

So the first one is what the website currently has (not every websites though):

```
$("form").submit(function () {
  // ....do something, maybe ajax submit of the form.....
});
```

and my *additional* that I want to add without editing any current scripts already found in the website:

```
$("form").submit(function () {
    $.getJSON("....");
});
```

The solution for me should be that the second script (*the additional*) will not interfere with any other form scripts.

**AN IDEA**

To add a class by using jQuery `addClass` to the forms of current page.

What is a solution for this?

Comment: None of the forms have id's?

Comment: @RatHat because this will be a solution on the "one size fits all" it must not play with ids. Of course, if somehow can I add through jquery a unique class to the form ?

Comment: You seem to have tried it... doesn't it work? What are you doing inside the `additional`-Callback? Just the `getJSON` call?

Comment: I think you should use `Promises` or jQuery's `Deferred`.

Comment: @Ciprianis Why should he use `Promises` ?! This seems too much for this particular use-case...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515069/jquery-check-if-event-exists-on-element

Comment: @Sebastian G. Marinescu - Well, from what I understand he wants to register form submissions. The idea was to submit the form and based on the received answer to register a submission or not.

Comment: @Ciprianis I have no idea what that has to do with promises of jQuery's deferred. This question is about whether or not you can find a hook that's strong enough to "take over" `stopImmediatePropagation` or not and does so in an unobtrusive way - sort of a way to be _notified_ of the event but not actually interfere with other handlers.

Comment: @Ciprianis Ok, now I think I understand your approach. But that would mean, that he has to update every already existing event-handler, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

I created a little Snippet to demonstrate the issue:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Registering form-submission as the first would be a possibility
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
    console.info('My first callback is executing');

    // Do some stuff here, but don't mess with the event-object 
    // (like preventing default or stopping the event-chain)
  });

  // Then afterwards everything else that *might* catch the event
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
    console.info('My second callback is executing');

    // Usually some Ajax-Handler-Callback, that handles sending the form,
    // will preventDefault() and stopImmediatePropagation() - that is why 
    // your general first listener must be registered before any of these callbacks

    console.warn('Second callback stops the event from bubbling/propagating');
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // This will never happen
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
    console.info('My third callback will never execute');
  });
  
  // Using a delegated event-listener with `useCapture` lets this execute first
  document.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    console.info('Capturing the event natively');
  }, true);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>My Website with a multi-handled form</h1>

<form class="" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="test" value="">
  <button type="submit" name="button">Send</button>
</form>
```

---

Output of the Snippet, when submitting the form:

> Capturing the event natively
>
> ```
> <form class action method="post">…</form>
> ```
>
> My first callback is executing
>
> ```
> <form class action method="post">…</form>
> ```
>
> My second callback is executing
>   Second callback stops the event from bubbling/propagating

---

### What did just happened?

By pressing the submit-button, our form emits the *submit*-event. The Browser starts with the event-propagation in a specified [event-order](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html). There are two phases of event-propagation: [event-capturing and event-bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4616720/1166642).

Now our *first called* event-listener is the one with the *useCapture*-directive.
This is during the **capture-phase** of the *event-propagation*.

Explanation for *useCapture* taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

> capture: A Boolean that indicates that events of this type will be
>   dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched to any
>   EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree.

When done, the Browser starts with the **bubbling-phase** of the *event-propagation*.

This is where all `$('element').on()` and `element.addEventListener()` (without the *useCapture* option) registered listeners are called in their appearing order.

During this phase our second listener is not only preventing default (not submitting the form the standard-way), but also stopping the event-propagation by calling `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`.

After that the *event-chain/event-propagation* stops immediately.

That is why our third listener will never execute.

> **On a side note**: When using jQuery and exiting an event-callback with
>   `return false`, jQuery will execute `e.preventDefault()` and
>   `e.stopPropagation()` automatically.
>
> See: http://api.jquery.com/on/

---

### Conclusion

You basically have two possibilities for your scenario:

1. Register your default general event-listener before anything else (first event-registration in Snippet).
2. Register an event-listener during the capture-phase, to capture the event and handle things before the other listeners from the bubbling-phase get called (last event-registration in Snippet).

With both methods you should be able to do your stuff without interfering with other event-listeners.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. I can not test it right now, however if I get this right, I have to place the "second handler" script and the "delegated event-handler" below the script that submits the form?

Comment: Hi @Xalloumokkelos, I just added more explanation to my answer. I hope everything is understandable now, if not let me know what confuses you.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
    $(document).on("submit", "form", function (e){
```

Complete example:

```
    <form id="form1"><input type="text" /><input type="submit" /></form>
    <form id="form2"><input type="text" /><input type="submit" /></form>
```

Js:

```
    $(document).on("submit", "form", function (e) {
      var oForm = $(this);
      var formId = oForm.attr("id");
      var firstValue = oForm.find("input").first().val();
      alert("Form '" + formId + " is being submitted, value of first input is: " + firstValue);
      return false;
     })

     [JS fiddle]: http://jsfiddle.net/pZ3Jn/
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to achieve is to track form submits.

Why not just use `$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(){});`?

It will be triggered on every form submit, no matter how it is being submitted.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Some already existing event handler
  $('#bir').on('submit', function(e) {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // Your universal form event handler
  $(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
    console.log('Additional functionality for: ' + $(this).attr('id'));
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="bir">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<form id="ikki">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: But what if an already existing event handler would also `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` ?

Comment: Well, the solution would be to do what you are suggesting, registering the "universal" event handler first. I think it is better to register one event handler on `document` as above than on every `form` element with `$('form')`.

Comment: Yeah, using delegated event-handlers is always nice, if you are handling multiple stuff on the same page... but if another event-handler would stop the bubbling, the delegated event-handler would _never_ execute - wouldn`t it?

Comment: What I am trying to say - If in your example the form with the id `ikki` would also have an event-handler, but that would stop the event-chain ( `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` ), then your delegated event-handler would still **not execute**!

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you mean and the solution is to register the "universal" handler first (as you are suggesting). However, I am yet to see anyone using `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`.

Comment: Ok, but many tutorials show the use of `return false;` at the end of a submit-handler, and most of the tutorials or people are using jQuery, so then it becomes relevant, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this issue a few times before and my solution was to capture all form nodes and associate them with a special action . This may not be practical but is a possible solution for you also .

**Example**

```
//Getting all form elements 

var formNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('form');

//loop through nodelist and add submit event and special class to each. 

for(var i = 0; i < formNodes.length; i++){

  formNodes[i].addEventListener('submit'  , registerAction)
  formNodes[i].className += "form-" + i;
}


/*This function captures the submitted form and determines 
the action to carry out based off class name .
e.preventDefault will stop page from reloading in case of
making ajax requests.
*/

function registerAction(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var formTarget = $(e.target).attr('class');

 switch(formTarget){

   case "form-0" :
     // Do something ...

     break;
   case "form-1" :
     // Do something else...
     break;

   default:
     break;


 }

  return false;
}
```

**Keep in mind that the logic inside registerAction can be alter to fit your needs
in this situation I used "case statement" because I feel it makes the most sense .**

This is not perfect but I hope it gives you an idea..

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that for example if a form has an ajax script on it, it
>   gets blocked by my additional script code.

No, it doesn't. You can bind many handlers on one element.

For rare cases, see the other suggestions, but If I got you right, your basic assumption was that binding a handler on an element cancel the previous one. Well, it doesn't.