# asp-fallback-test for loading jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, cdn, asp.net-core-3.1

I am building an ASP-NET CORE 3.1 MVC Web Application. I wish to use the CDNJS network to provide my script resource files, and since this is a production application, I must have a fallback to a local copy for when the CDN might be offline. This is a fairly basic task and I can successfully load multiple libraries such as Bootstrap 4.5, jQuery 3.3, etc.

As you may know, ASPNET core script tag-helpers have awesome functions built in to do what I want to do automatically. When trying to load `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` I am unable to decide what my fallback test function should actually be. The ????? below represents the code I cannot make work.

Basically, I need to write JS code that returns `false` when the CDN is not available. This code will be plugged into the ?????.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"
        asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"
        asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && ?????">
</script>
```

Comment: Any update? Does my reply solve your issue?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the fallback-test attribute a Javascript expression to use for the fallback test. Should resolve to true if the primary script loads successfully.

After check the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`, we could find it depend the `jQuery.validator` js.

So I suggest you could add below expression:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"
        asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.validator && window.jQuery.validator.unobtrusive"
         >
</script>
```

Comment: This is the fallback for unobtrusive validation plugin `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` ... I need the one for unobtrusive AJAX

Answer (score 2):

Just discovered this post while looking for the same answer.

I found that

```
asp-fallback-test="getEvents($(document)[0]).submit"
```

Worked, where getEvents is defined as follows (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12899236/4254458)

```
    function getEvents(element) {
        var elemEvents = $._data(element, "events");
        var allDocEvnts = $._data(document, "events");
        for (var evntType in allDocEvnts) {
            if (allDocEvnts.hasOwnProperty(evntType)) {
                var evts = allDocEvnts[evntType];
                for (var i = 0; i < evts.length; i++) {
                    if ($(element).is(evts[i].selector)) {
                        if (elemEvents == null) {
                            elemEvents = {};
                        }
                        if (!elemEvents.hasOwnProperty(evntType)) {
                            elemEvents[evntType] = [];
                        }
                        elemEvents[evntType].push(evts[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return elemEvents;
    }
```

Comment: Simplified - asp-fallback-test: "window.jQuery && window.jQuery._data(window.jQuery(document)[0], 'events') && window.jQuery._data(window.jQuery(document)[0], 'events').submit"

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"  
  asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"  
  asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.validator"  
  crossorigin="anonymous"  
  integrity="sha384-Fnqn3nxp3506LP/7Y3j/25BlWeA3PXTyT1l78LjECcPaKCV12TsZP7yyMxOe/G/k">
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validation.unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"  
  asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"  
  asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.validator && window.jQuery.validator.unobtrusive"  
  crossorigin="anonymous"  
  integrity="sha384-JrXK+k53HACyavUKOsL+NkmSesD2P+73eDMrbTtTk0h4RmOF8hF8apPlkp26JlyH">
```